# Play Framework 2.0 - asJson() always returns null

Tags: java, json, playframework-2.0, request

This is a simple form with username and email fields.

```
<form method="post" action="@routes.Application.signup()" enctype="application/json">
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
    <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
</form>
```

Now I try to parse `request().body()` as in the [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.4/JavaBodyParsers).

```
@BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)
public static Result signup() {
    RequestBody body = request().body();
    return ok("Got json: " + body.asJson());
}
```

This returns null. `request().body().toString()` doesn't though, in fact, I can print the request, which is displayed as:

```
DefaultRequestBody(Some(Map(username -> List(james), email -> List(hello@sdfs.com))),None,None,None,None,None,false)
```

Basically I want to extract the name and email from the request but the toJson method always returns null.

Comment: May have something to do with the enctype ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/4150273/1536382

Comment: Well I have tried removing the enctype attribute entirely and it still remains null, but the docs say it should be set to application/json.

Comment: Is 'play.mvc.Http.RequestBody' being imported? It could be you're importing the wrong type of RequestBody..?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't been able to find this documented anywhere, but I've run into the same problem. The issue is with your content type header. If your header says text then you can get the body as a string and the body as json will be null. Likewise if your header says json then the body as string will be null and the body as json will be parsed.